# What is regex for this kind of string

Tags: regex, wildcard, pcre

```
1.5V6A 6Q2A 6Q 5Q
2.FA 7A EQ2A 799Q
3.M Y77A279791
4.V59 2 5A266
5.Q7Q E7Q 7 7AQ2A 7A29
```

What would be the regex/wildcard to find these kind with spaces in middle and without definite length ?

I am unable to figure it out. I want to find them and replace them with same but with a line break after each one.

find these kind of occurences 5V6A 6Q2A 6Q 5Q and replace with a (linebreak) afterwards

Example:

5V6A 6Q2A 6Q 5Q Mr.Christopher M Krieg Indianapolis,IN $ Eight Million Three Hundred Five Thousand Seven Hundred Thirty One AND Ten %Twenty Years AND Ten.Four % (Purchase Value Reduction 20.75%) (Monthly Principal Reduction 7.55%) (Total Interest Reduction1957%) Dr.Kirk C Lucero FA 7A EQ2A 799Q

I want to introduce a line break afterwards the occurrence. Is it possible?

Comment: `^[A-Z\d]+(\s[A-Z\d]+)+$`

Comment: Why complicated? `\S+` will find all of those (assuming the line numbering is not part of the data). Even easier, just replace spaces with newlines.

Comment: thank you. im using sublime text to find these kinds in a text file. I want to find, replace them with same with a line break at the end of them each. All of them have only capital letters, numbers and spaces between them. If you can help...

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to be ok:

```
\d+\.(\w+( |$))+
```

Test:

```js
`1.5V6A 6Q2A 6Q 5Q
2.FA 7A EQ2A 799Q
3.M Y77A279791
4.V59 2 5A266
5.Q7Q E7Q 7 7AQ2A 7A29`
.split("\n").every(RegExp.prototype.test.bind(/\d+\.(\w+( |$))+/))
```

Comment: \w.+\d.+(\w+( |$))+

This seems to help somehow for my requirement. But Im unable to figure out how to replace with same, but just add a linebreak afterwards the occurence.